# JavaScript closures surprising

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var a = [];
var b = ['abc','def'];
for(var c of b) {
  var c_ = c.slice();
  a.push(function(){alert(c_)});
}

a[0]();
a[1]();
```

Result is seing the message "def" twice. This is entirely unexpected. How do I do this in JavaScript? If it were `alert(c)` I could understand but `c_` is clearly a copy of `c` and is properly scoped by other language's standards.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is always function scoped. `let` is block scoped!.